# Table doesn't work on small sizes (like mobile phones)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know why, but width of my table on very small sizes is going over the background on the right ( outside the screen of the phone ) . On 412 px it works, but on 320 px don't want to be nice and my table go outside screen and everything is cut.

```css
.ania-center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <hr>
        <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Rejestracja on-line
          <strong>bez kolejek!</strong>
        </h2>
        <hr>
        <h2 class="text-center">Lista lekarzy</h2>
        <br/>
        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped ania-center">
          <tr>
            <th>Imie i nazwisko</th>
            <th>Gabinet</th>
            <th>Telefon</th>
            <th>Rejestracja on-line</th>
          </tr>
          @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{$doctor['imie']}} {{$doctor['nazwisko']}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{$doctor['gabinet']}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{$doctor['telefon']}}
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="terminy/{{$doctor['id']}}">umów wizyte</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the table inside a div and give it a  class **.table-responsive**

This class doesn't work directly on the table.

See result below:

```css
.ania-center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <hr>
        <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Rejestracja on-line
          <strong>bez kolejek!</strong>
        </h2>
        <hr>
        <h2 class="text-center">Lista lekarzy</h2>
        <br/>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped ania-center">
            <tr>
              <th>Imie i nazwisko</th>
              <th>Gabinet</th>
              <th>Telefon</th>
              <th>Rejestracja on-line</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{$doctor['imie']}} {{$doctor['nazwisko']}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{$doctor['gabinet']}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{$doctor['telefon']}}
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="terminy/{{$doctor['id']}}">umów wizyte</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank U very much :) Works

Comment: in addition to wenus answer dont forget metatag 
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">